# Inserting and printing from LinkedList

Tags: c++

I have created a LinkedList that takes from a student class. I'm having trouble either inserting the data from a file into the LinkedList, or retrieving that data back.

This is the file I'm taking input from:

```
117324 Chris Johnson Freshman 15 47
231098 Pat Smith Freshman 13 42
220982 Sally Larson Sophomore 48 168
320981 Mary Wilson Sophomore 52 149
439083 Larry Edwards Junior 82 210
439871 Samuel Johnson Freshman 16 31
465132 Ashley Edwrads Senior 112 359
```

This is how I'm adding the data to the LinkedList:

```
 int i = 1;
 while(!StudentFile.eof())
     {
       int id;
       string firstname;
       string lastname;
       string level;
       double credithours;
       double gradepoints;

       StudentFile >> id >> firstname >> lastname >> level >> credithours >> gradepoints;

       Student myStudent(id, firstname, lastname, level, credithours, gradepoints);
       myStudentList.insert(i,myStudent);

       i++;
}
```

This is how I'm trying to print the data out:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= myStudentList.getLength(); i++)
  {
    Student StuPtr = myStudentList.getEntry(i);
    cout << "Student: " << StuPtr.getID() << "; " << StuPtr.getFirstName() << " " << StuPtr.getLastName() << ", " << StuPtr.getLevel() << ", " << StuPtr.getGPA() << " GPA\n";
  }
```

Here are my insert and getEntry method definitions (as well as getNodeAt):

```
template<class ItemType>
void LinkedList<ItemType>::insert(int newPosition, const ItemType& newEntry)
{
  bool ableToInsert = (newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= itemCount + 1);
  if(ableToInsert)
  {
    SLNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new SLNode<ItemType>(newEntry);

    if(newPosition == 1)
    {
      newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);
      headPtr = newNodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
      SLNode<ItemType>* prevPtr = getNodeAt(newPosition - 1);

      newNodePtr->setNext(prevPtr->getNext());
      prevPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);
    }
    itemCount++;
  }
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType LinkedList<ItemType>::getEntry(int position)const
{
  bool ableToGet = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount);
  if(ableToGet)
  {
    SLNode<ItemType>* nodePtr = getNodeAt(position);
    return nodePtr->getItem();
  }
  else
  {
    string message = "getEntry() called with an empty list or ";
    message = message + "invalid position";
    throw(PrecondViolatedExcep(message));
  }
}

template<class ItemType>
SLNode<ItemType>* LinkedList<ItemType>::getNodeAt(int position)const
{
  if( (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount) )
  {
  SLNode<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
  for(int skip = 1; skip < position; skip++)
  {
  curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
  }
  return curPtr;
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Here is my SLNode.h:

```
#ifndef SLNODE_H
#define SLNODE_H
template <typename T>
class SLNode // A node in a singly linked list
{
private:
    T item;
    SLNode* next; // we can only go "forward" along our chain
public:

    SLNode(T anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr) {}
    SLNode(T anItem, SLNode* nextSLNode) : item(anItem), next(nextSLNode) {}
    T getItem() const { return item; }
    SLNode* getNext() const { return next; }
    void setItem(T newItem) { item = newItem; }
    void setNext(SLNode* nextSLNode) { next = nextSLNode; }
};
#endif
```

Private member variable for the LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<Student> myStudentList;
```

And here is the output that I'm getting:

```
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
Student: 117324; Chris Johnson, Freshman, 3.13333 GPA
```

Comment: What is the purpose behind the loop in `getNodeAt` that just does `curPtr->getNext();` without retaining the result. Pretty sure that should be `curPtr = curPtr->getNext();`

Comment: Yeah your right, I changed it but I'm still getting the same problem?

Comment: What does your `SLNode` constructor look like?

Comment: Updated with the SLNode file.

Comment: I cannot see what is wrong from the code, so either your code does not match the compiled program or something else is wrong. Attach a debugger and step to right after the `while (!StudentFile.eof())` loop. Is `myStudentList` correctly constructed?

Comment: Your index variable is starting at 1 and going to list->getLength(). Array and list indices usually start at 0